# Why am I not able to compile this java code?

Tags: java, compilation, javac

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class ExplicitChannelRead {

    /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FileInputStream fIn = null;
        FileChannel fChan = null;
        ByteBuffer mBuf;
        int count;

        try{
            fIn = new FileInputStream("text.txt");

            fChan = fIn.getChannel();

            mBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(128);

            do{
                count = fChan.read(mBuf);

                if(count!=-1){
                    mBuf.rewind();

                    for(int i =0; i<count; i++)
                        System.out.print((char) mBuf.get());

                }
            }while(count!=-1);

            System.out.println();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("I/O Error : " + e);
        }finally{
            try{
                if(fChan!=null)
                    fChan.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error closing Channel.");
            }

            try{
                if(fIn!= null)
                    fIn.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error closing file.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile this code in Command prompt I get the error

```
ExplictChannelRead.java:58:error:class, interface, or enum expected }
```

When I compile it in my IDE I get the following error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at nio_path.ExplicitChannelRead.main(ExplicitChannelRead.java:12)"
```

I copied the entire code from a book.

Comment: What's line 58? What's line 12?

Comment: What is the name of the file that you are compiling?

Comment: Do you have a file named text.txt?

Comment: For your "Command prompt error", did you mean "ExplicitChannelRead.java..."? (Explict -> Explicit)

Comment: the name of the file is obviously same as the classname .java

Comment: Why the upvote, for heaven's sake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine for me :)

You have a hanging } after your quoted text...  Make sure you have matching braces...

Answer (score 2):

There are 11 `{` characters and 12 `}` characters in your source code.

Find the missing `{` or remove the `}` which is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a } at the end of the file, you seem to be missing one.

Comment: I had an extra }. I deleted it.

Comment: no he should remove the last }

Answer (score 0):

It compiles fine for me using JDK 1.7.0_01.